# .env file contents not being substituted during docker compose build although in same directory

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, docker-compose, .env

My docker-compose.yaml file is as follows:

```
services:
  planview:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: planview
    environment:
      - AZURE_TENANT_ID=${AZURE_TENANT_ID}
      - AZURE_CLIENT_ID=${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
      - AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=${AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Everything is in one directory so that can't be the issue.

In my Python script I'm also retrieving the credentials with the following code

```
load_dotenv(".env")
client_id = os.getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_ID')
tenant_id = os.getenv('AZURE_TENANT_ID')
client_secret = os.getenv('AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET')
```

When running `docker compose up`, the image is created, the container runs and the script is executed. It's only when trying to use `docker compose build` to create an image that has the credentials so anyone who has it can run is when I receive the error

```
ValueError: client_id should be the id of an Azure Active Directory application
```

There has to be something wrong with my docker-compose file but I can't see where the error is or if I'm missing something. I've also tried `env_file:` without any success. The credentials provided are definitely valid.

Does anyone see where the issue is?

EDIT:

Dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.10

ADD planview.py .

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY . /code/app

CMD ["python3", "/planview.py"]
```

Comment: Can you provide the Dockerfile in your question aswell? Maybe you'll need to declare those variables in your Dockerfile so the Final builded image has it.

Comment: @RenanFernandes
Have added it as an edit

Answer (score 1):

Try adding those variables in your Dockerfile so it is available in runtime. Should look like this:

```
COPY . /code/app

# Set the environment variables
ENV AZURE_TENANT_ID=""
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_ID=""
ENV AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=""

CMD ["python3", "/planview.py"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I Tried it as you mentioned but still receive the same error. I can't understand it.

Should I be using something other than ```docker compose build``` ?

Comment: @Elarbe I usually run with "docker-compose up -d --build" .   Can check your container environment with the exec command?  example: docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> sh -c 'echo $AZURE_TENANT_ID'. Or get inside it's console and and type echo $AZURE_TENANT_ID

Comment: The container doesn't manage to launch because of the error, so I haven't tried starting it again and sshing yet. I will have another look soon and let you know.

Comment: you can Echo in your Dockerfile too So you'll see it prompt during the build logs, just add the line "RUN echo $AZURE_TENANT_ID" after the declaration